# Converting svg rect with background image to black-white

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am creating scatter graphs of sports team logos using d3 / svg, and am interested in making certain logos black and white. Here (dont worry about not following all of the variables) is a couple lines of code where I draw the logos.

```
logoMarkers
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${(xScale(+d[xOption.value][xOption.objKey]) - 0.5 * logoRadius)}, ${(yScale(+d[yOption.value][yOption.objKey]) - 0.5 * logoRadius)})`)
        .attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0)
        .attr('height', logoRadius)
        .attr('width', logoRadius)
        .attr('fill', d => `url(#teamlogo-${d.teamId})`)
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('opacity', d => this.props.focusTeam === 'none' ? 1 : (d.teamId === this.props.focusTeam ? 1 : 0.20));
```

...this code makes all logos besides the Duke logo have opacity 0.20, however I would also like to make the non-Duke logos black and white. Is this possible? I would prefer to not have to actually save black-and-white versions of the logo in my s3 bucket where I pull the images from, and would much rather prefer to simply convert the images to black-and-white somehow in my code.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following filter definition on your page somewhere.

```
<filter id="saturate">
  <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
</filter>
```

Then add the following to the non-Duke elements.

```
.attr('filter', 'url(#saturate)')
```

Example:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="saturate">
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="75" fill="red" filter="url(#saturate)"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="75" fill="green" filter="url(#saturate)"/>
  <circle cx="225" cy="75" r="75" fill="blue" filter="url(#saturate)"/>
</svg>
```